# Limit scrolling direction in Feathers ScrollContainer

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, feathers-ui

I have a Feathers ScrollContainer with a starling display object added under it.
When a child object is larger than the ScrollContainer, it will automatically allow scrolling.
I want to restrict the scrolling direction to be vertical only, and not horizontal.
Any tips?
Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1):

Setting the scroll policy to off on the horizontal and auto on the vertical should do what you want:

```
YourScrollContainerNameHere.horizontalScrollPolicy = Scroller.SCROLL_POLICY_OFF;
YourScrollContainerNameHere.verticalScrollPolicy  = Scroller.SCROLL_POLICY_AUTO;
```

See the Scroll Policies section @ http://feathersui.com/help/scroll-container.html